# Retrieving data from another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Excel 2002. And i would like to know the easiest method in grabbing data from another spreadsheet whenever a key number is inserted.

This is first worksheet. I need data to be automated inserted to Column E whenever Column C is entered with numbers. These numbers are not any numbers but key numbers from worksheet 2

[image]

This is the second worksheet. So for example, I key in 208 in worksheet 1, Column E from worksheet 1 should automatically grab AFI number from Column G of worksheet 2.

[image]

Additional : Worksheet 1 and worksheet 2 have primary fields which is "Monthly Payment"
I'm contemplating between Vlookup. Please advise.

UPDATES :

ERROR MESSAGE 1 :

[image]

ERROR MESSAGE 2 :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use vlookup for this case. Paste this to E2 on Sheet1 and drag down

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2;Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999;4;FALSE);"")
```

If your data sheet name is different than Sheet2 you can change it from the formula.

Regards,

Comment: hi @trevize, i encountered an error upon using your formula, please see my OP.

Comment: @Newbie Did you try using `,` instead of `;`?

Comment: @Jerry is right, comma is regional-settings dependent. try this:     =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE),"")

Comment: Hi @TrevizeDaneel, used **,** instead of **;** came out error as name in the field box

Comment: @Newbie My bad, I have checked and IFERROR function does not exist in excel prior to 2007. Eighter put this

    =VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE)
or 

    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE),"")

the second one should show blank cell if no match is found.

Comment: Hi @TrevizeDaneel, the first formula works great. Thank you! But the 2nd formula throws back with an error, will be great to show blank cell though.

Comment: Well thats becasue I made a mistake in it the correct one should be :

    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($C2,Sheet2!$D$2:$G$9999,4,FALSE))